# jira - JQL show all Child of an issue

Tags: jira, jql

I'm trying do:

```
project = tet1 AND issueLinkType = "is a child of"
```

Shows all issues that are a child but I'm trying to see how I can show only issues from a specific parent issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was

```
issue in linkedIssues("MDC-27","is a parent of")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all issues that are linked to one issue you can use the below :

```html
issue in linkedIssues("AD-11605")
```